# Password reset code is not returned

Tags: php

For a Reset Password form I want a reset_code (that is stored in DB) to be returned for in the email. The only thing that is not returning is.... the reset_code. I am working with MVC Flight (php framework).
My Model:

```
public function forgotPassword($email)
{
    $stmt = $this->Database()->getCon()->prepare( "SELECT `reset_code` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = :email" );
    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    $result = $row['reset_code'];

    if( $row->rowCount() > 0 ) {
        return $result;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
if ($UserModel->forgotPassword($email)) {
$reset_code = $UserModel->forgotPassword($email);
if ($email == $email) {
    $email_message = "$reset_code";
    $headers = 'From: ' . $emailme . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 1 (Highest)\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\r\n";
    $headers .= "Importance: High\r\n";
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
}
$err['data'] = array("status" => "success", "type" => "success", "message" => "Er is een email met een unieke link verzonden naar $email."); }
```

The mailscript works and in the controller I have let the unimportant things for this question away. I think the mistake is in the model, but I dont know where/what.

Comment: what is `if ($email == $email) {` supposed to do? isn't that always true? For your issue at hand, what does `var_dump($reset_code)` give you in the model and  in the controller?

Comment: @Gordon the `if ($email == $email) {` part is for activating the code. The var_dump thing gives me nothing ;/

Comment: if it gives you nothing, the likely explanation is that there is no reset_code in your database for the entered email. inspect the $row or query your database manually. as for `(email==email)`: this makes no sense. it will always be true. it's the same as `if (1==1)` or `if(true)`

Comment: @Gordon Yeah its really weird but (dont know if allowed:) https://i.gyazo.com/6861f378d8d59c83b45d83ff098d2d2f.png shows there is a reset_code for each user.

Comment: var_dump($row) please

Comment: I  think the var_dump will not show up because my model is incorrect. But I dont know where it is going wrong. ;/ @Gordon

Comment: what do you mean by "not show up". you should get some output, just not the one you expect to get. So $row will likely dump a null or empty array. right?

Comment: on a side note: calling `$UserModel->forgotPassword($email);` twice is inefficient. it makes a database call. call it once and assign the return value. then check if the return value is false instead of calling the method again. db calls are expensive.

Comment: @Gordon  I have changed my model to this: https://i.gyazo.com/c474a91e29bd527021065befa969e039.png and I am echo'ing the $reset_code in the alert and then it echo's **1**

Comment: which means `if( $row->rowCount() > 0 ) {` returned true. we are not making progress this way though. Like I said, do var_dump($row) to see what the fetched database record contains.

Comment: @Gordon think I am too amateurish in PHP. I have added the var_dump in the controller but it is simply not showing up anything. What is like logic because there is no session, right (don't know if that last part is super dumb tho ghehe..)

Comment: put it in your forgotPassword method right after $row = $stmt->fetch();

Comment: @Gordon Added the whole controller. now. This controller does not show a page, but takes care about an ajax-request. So I dont know where the var_dump would show up.

Comment: An Ajax request is just an HTTP request. It's not different from opening a URL in your browser. I suggest you install https://www.getpostman.com and then fire your request from there, instead of going end to end. The response you get from the url should contain the var_dump output.

Comment: Note that I had to rollback your question because you removed the model code for the longer controller code. you had the shortened controller code and the full code now.